# How to successfully complete a namenode restart with 5TB worth of edit files to process

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, namenode

I have a namenode that had to be brought down for an emergency that has not had an FSImage taken for 9 months and has about 5TB worth of edit files to process in its next restart.  The secondary namenode has not been running (or had any checkpoint operations performed) since about 9 months ago, thus the 9 month old FSImage.

There are about 7.8 million inodes in the HDFS cluster.  The machine has about 260GB of total memory.

We've tried a few different combinations of Java heap size, GC algorithms, etc... but have not been able to find a combination that allows the restart to complete without eventually slowing down to a crawl due to FGCs.

I have 2 questions:
1.  Has anyone found a namenode configuration that allows this large of an edit file backlog to complete successfully?

2. An alternate approach I've considered is restarting the namenode with only a manageable subset of the edit files present.  Once the namenode comes up and creates a new FSImage, bring it down, copy the next subset of edit files over, and then restart it.  Repeat until it's processed the entire set of edit files.  Would this approach work?  Is it safe to do, in terms of the overall stability of the system and the file system?

Comment: Do you have a secondary Name Node in your cluster?

Comment: We do have one configured, but it is not currently running.  The last time it was brought up was actually about 9 months ago when the last FSImage was taken, it looks like.

Comment: That's too bad.  The job of the SNN is to keep the edits down to a manageable size.

Comment: If your host for the SNN is not the same as the NN host and has the same memory, then you could try restarting it and letting it process the backlog.  https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/03/a-guide-to-checkpointing-in-hadoop/.  It should basically do the same as what you want in approach 2.

Comment: Would the SNN attempt to process the entire backlog of edit files before attempting to create another FSImage?  If so, it would probably run out of memory also, I would think.  Or are you suggesting to allow the SNN to work on a subset of the edit files at a time, like what I was thinking for the NN?

Comment: No, you can specify the number of edits via `dfs.namenode.checkpoint.txns`.  The SNN will checkpoint every `dfs.namenode.checkpoint.txns` edits.  See https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/namenode/SecondaryNameNode.java.  You should bump up `dfs.namenode.num.checkpoints.retained` to something higher (defaults to 2) just in case, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We were able to get through the 5TB backlog of edits files using a version of what I suggested in my question (2) on the original post.  Here is the process we went through:

### Solution:

1. Make sure that the namenode is "isolated" from the datanodes.  This can be done by either shutting down the datanodes, or just removing them from the slaves list while the namenode is offline.  This is done to keep the namenode from being able to communicate with the datanodes before the entire backlog of edits files is processed.
2. Move the entire set of edits files to a location outside of what is configured on the `dfs.namenode.name.dir` property of the namenode's `hdfs-site.xml`file.
3. Move (or copy if you would like to maintain a backup) the *next* subset of edits files to be processed to the `dfs.namenode.name.dir` location.  If you are not familiar with the naming convention for the FSImage and edits files, take a look at the example below.  It will hopefully clarify what is meant by *next* subset of edits files.
4. Update file `seen_txid` to contain the value of the last transaction represented by the last edits file from the subset you copied over in step (3).  So if the last edits file is `edits_0000000000000000011-0000000000000000020`, you would want to update the value of `seen_txid` to `20`.  This essentially fools the namenode into thinking this subset is the *entire* set of edits files.
5. Start up the namenode.  If you take a look at the `Startup Progress` tab of the HDFS Web UI, you will see that the namenode will start with the latest present FSImage, process through the edits files present, create a new FSImage file, and then go into safemode while it waits for the datanodes to come online.
6. Bring down the namenode
7. There will be `edits_inprogress_########` file created as a placeholder by the namenode.  Unless this is the **final** set of edits files to process, delete this file.
8. Repeat steps 3-7 until you've worked through the entire backlog of edits files.
9. Bring up datanodes.  The namenode should get out of safemode once it's been able to confirm the location of a number of data blocks.
10. Set up a secondary namenode, or high availability for your cluster, so that the FSImage will periodically get created from now on.

### Example:

Let's say we have FSImage `fsimage_0000000000000000010` and a bunch of edits files: `edits_0000000000000000011-0000000000000000020`
`edits_0000000000000000021-0000000000000000030`
`edits_0000000000000000031-0000000000000000040`
`edits_0000000000000000041-0000000000000000050`
`edits_0000000000000000051-0000000000000000060`
...
`edits_0000000000000000091-0000000000000000100`

Following the steps outlined above:

1. All datanodes brought offline.
2. All edits files copied from `dfs.namenode.name.dir` to another location, ex: `/tmp/backup`
3. Let's process 2 files at a time.  So copy `edits_0000000000000000011-0000000000000000020` and `edits_0000000000000000021-0000000000000000030` over to the `dfs.namenode.name.dir` location.
4. Update `seen_txid` to contain a value of `30` since this is the last transaction we will be processing during this run.
5. Start up the namenode, and confirm through the HDFS Web UI's `Startup Progress` tab that it correctly used `fsimage_0000000000000000010` as a starting point and then processed `edits_0000000000000000011-0000000000000000020` and `edits_0000000000000000021-0000000000000000030`.  It then created a new FSImage file fsimage_0000000000000000030` and entered safemode, waiting for the datanodes to come up.
6. Bring down the namenode
7. Delete the placeholder file `edits_inprogress_########` since this is not the final set of edits files to be processsed.
8. Proceed with the next run and repeat until all edits files have been processed.

Answer (score 0):

If your hadoop is HA enabled, then StandBy NN should have taken care of this, in case of non-HA your secondary NN.

Check logs of these namenode processes as why it is not able to merge/fail.

These below parameters drive your edit files save, and it shouldnt have created these many files.

```
dfs.namenode.checkpoint.period
dfs.namenode.checkpoint.txns
```

other way to manually perform the merge but this would be **temporary**.

```
hdfs dfsadmin -safemode enter
hdfs dfsadmin -rollEdits
hdfs dfsadmin -saveNamespace
hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

Running above command should merge and save the namespaces.

Comment: I edited the original posting to mention that the SNN has not been running (or had a checkpoint operation executed) in about 9 months.  That is why the most recent FSImage is also that old.

Comment: For the temporary operations that you mentioned, those would have to be run with the NN running, right?

Comment: If you have started the SNN it would automatically merge FS image. yes the commands which i have mentioned needs to be executed on active NN.